# firefox debugger not showing 401 response

Tags: authentication, firefox

Firefox 103.0

Eventually trying to troubleshoot some authentication issues, but starting with a simple (non-ssl) internal site.

When a website wants authentication, it responds with a 401 error and next browser request has the Authorization header.

With Wireshark, I see the 401 and the browser response. (non-ssl site of course)
With Firefox debugger, network view, I only see a 200 stuats.  "Persist logs" is checked, so it shouldn't clear the network log.

Is there any way to see the 401 and the full authentication negotiation?